# What is the Russian equivalent of 'perfect is as perfect does'?

Tags: перевод, идиомы

I've encountered this saying multiple times in English, but even though I'm a native Russian speaker, I can't find an exact equivalent of this saying in Russian.

Perhaps someone here knows?

Comment: Could you please expand the meaning of this saying? Thank you!

Comment: Is it a pun on "stupid is as stupid does"?

Comment: @IgorG: the original one is "handsome is as handsome does", and the variant with "stupid" is modeled after it. There are a lot of expressions using this pattern, but how it translates to "perfect", that I don't know. _Нормально делай — нормально будет_ maybe

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I have no idea what this means, or more specifically, how to apply it. If it's meant to encourage the listener to be "perfect", I'm hard put to imagine recommending such arrogance to anyone. Or is it a sarcastic reproach for someone striving or claiming to be perfect? I can't make heads or tails of it in English, to say nothing of Russian.

Comment: @CocoPop, does the following interpretation seem viable: "Perfect [one] is, because perfect [things he] does"? I can see such interpretation working with negative adjectives like "Глуп я есмь ибо глупости творю", but any positive adjective makes it sound like bragging or maybe condescending, which isn't typical style of a common saying or a proverb, but still does it make some sense?

Comment: @IgorG: I guess it could be interpreted like that, but I agree with you that it's such an odd thing to say, so arrogant. And I googled it and saw that people say this, but I still can't quite understand what they mean. I'm thinking it's meant to be sarcastic, which is hard to express/interpret from the written word.

Comment: [native English speaker]  The saying I have always heard is "handsome is as handsome does".  The meaning, roughly, is that a meritorious person is recognised by their actions, not their appearance.  "Handsome" here does not so much mean physically attractive but rather generous, worthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`По плодам их узнаете их` and a whole family of similar idioms, such as `человека дела красят`, including postmodern memes (*не губы красят женщину, а женщина красит губы*)

Comment: Близко по смыслу; не красна изба углами, красна пирогами.